# Hospedagem de web service é igual a um site com páginas?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile com Xamarin. Essa aplicação é uma tela para autorizar ou não desconto acima do autorizado pelos vendedores. Então, tenho um *web service* que vai no banco e pega todas as informações pertinentes ao cliente e alimenta o aplicativo que estará na mão de quem tem poder para autorizar.

O *web service* deverá ser hospedado da mesma forma que um site? Nesse caso, provavelmente em uma intranet, provavelmente, eu ainda não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hospedagem essencialmente sim. Ou não, depende da tecnologia usada, mas não da funcionalidade.

Pelas *tags* está usando a Web API, o que me parece correto. O que diferencia esta tecnologia do MVC é que ela não gera uma *view* tradicional e sim um dado a ser processado pelo cliente. A forma que isto vai servidor não muda nada.

Se tiver algum motivo para hospedar de forma diferente é requisito da aplicação não porque é um *web service*.

Comment: Big, vamos usar webapi como back end e serviços Rest para isso e o mobile(front) vai consumir isso. Essa pergunta o cliente me fez, em relação a hospedagem.

Comment: Ou seja, pela resposta do Bigown, eu vou fazer uma hospedagem normal, como eu faço em um site e correr para o abraço